# call a function inside a jQuery plugin from outside on-click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, mention

i am using following library for auto complete and mention username in my application. my question is that how can i trigger init: function from onClick of a anchor tag instead of writing in text area. any suggestion? Here is a function that i tried to write.
here is the plugin
http://podio.github.io/jquery-mentions-input/

```
$("a").on('click', '.tag_user_btn', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       var txtPost = $(this).parents('.post-comment').find('textarea');
       txtPost.val(txtPost.val()+" @a").focus().init();//call initilize function of library
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation (the "Methods"-part), the `init()` method is actually exposed on the instance of the plugin. Example:

```
var mention = $('textarea.mention').mentionsInput({}); // Apply the plugin
mention.init(); // call the init() method
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the source of the problem but

`$("a").on('click', '.tag_user_btn', function(event) { //WRONG`
This is wrong. [jQuery documentation for .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Correct syntax `$(parentSelector).on('click', 'childSelector', function()`

Instead use (for ajax event handling)

`$(document).on('click', 'a.tag_user_btn', function(event) {`

or for non-ajax event handling

`$('a.tag_user_btn').click(function(event)` which is a shorthand for
`$('a.tag_user_btn').on('click', function(event))`